# See historical load of a mssql db server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm looking to **schedule a resource heavy job** on the database.
I'd like to **see the historical load of the MSSQL server** to determine a time slot.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Start recording: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3932406/Top-10-SQL-Server-Counters-for-Monitoring-SQL-Server-Performance.htm

Answer (score 0):

There is [DBCC MEMORYSTATUS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907877/en-us) to get a tons of memory information. you can also refer to previous [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28952/cpu-utilization-by-database) to find the utilization.

Answer (score 0):

A nice easy way to get the information that you want is to use a SQL Server feature called the data collector.

There is a nice step by step tutorial on how to set this up here:

[SQL SERVER – Configure Management Data Collection in Quick Steps](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/04/13/sql-server-configure-management-data-collection-in-quick-steps-t-sql-tuesday-005/)

You can also create your own data collectors so that you can persist DMV information (remember DMVs only show information since the last time SQL server was restarted).