# How to track query back to Linq To Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql

Using the [query posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28952/cpu-utilization-by-database), I was able to identify the super ugly, crazy query that has caused our server CPU to peg at 100. However, other than stepping through every Linq To Sql repository method in our application and examining the generated query, I have no idea how to track the query back to the responsible Linq To Sql.

Anyone know the fastest way to do this?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a particularly automatic way of doing that.

The best way is to find the table that is used the least often, and find the Linq to Sql queries that reference that table and then examine them. I am assuming that not every Linq to Sql query in your application uses the same database table.

To qualify - by used the least often, I mean used the least often in your code base, rather than has a query executed against it least often.